# Will a thread die if the calling function ends?

Tags: pthreads

Consider a thread t1 that executes a function hello(). I am creating and invoking the  thread t1 from inside a function  func(). My question is will the thread t1 die if  func() comes to an end even though the thread has not ended and still has work to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads do not keep track of which thread has created them and have no way to know if the creating thread has ended.

Threads are ended only:

- if the function called at thread creation terminates
- if the thread calls pthread_exit()
- if a thread receives a signal with pthread_kill(thread_id, sig) and the handler terminates the thread.
- if another thread calls pthread_cancel(thread_id). The thread must know the thread_id of the thread to kill and there are means to forbid cancellation.
- if the process terminates.

Comment: Great answer. Just a little doubt here. What happens if the calling function is not a thread and just a regular function? what happens if the function ends?